# Trouble debugging using PhpStorm when having command line inputs

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to debug my php script using PhpStorm and xdebug.

See my xdebug configurations below,
[image]

[image]

As for the breakpoints, I have added two of them to a simple script which reverses an array, 
[image]

I debug using the default debug configurations,

[image]

The first breakpoint works fine and I am able inspect the variables. But I cannot seem to move the control to the second breakpoint. This is how my screen looks after moving from the first breakpoint and executing line num 14. Line 14 takes in an input from the command line,

So, I tried entering inputs in the console, (can see the 3 i entered)
[image]

The debugger looks blank,
[image]

I am getting myself familiar with php and xdebug, so I guess the problem should be something trivial. What do you think?

Comment: Did you try with F8 (Step Over) instead of F7 (Step Into) ?

Comment: Yeah.. I was able to F8 into line 14. I did the same F8 when on line 14.